# OCaml repeating entire signature in implementation

Tags: module, ocaml, sml

Suppose I have a module `A`, with the following interface and implementation files:

```
(* a.mli *)
module type A_SIG =
sig
    val f: int -> int
    ...
end

(* a.ml *)
module A : A_SIG =
struct
    let f x = x + 1
    ...
end
```

Compiling `a.mli` followed by `a.ml` fails, with error `Unbound module type A_SIG`. Duplicating the entire signature in the implementation file fixes it.

Why is this the case? It seems that the following works in SML:

```
(* a.sig *)
signature A_SIG =
sig
    val f: int -> int
    ...
end

(* a.sml *)
structure A : A_SIG =
struct
   fun f x = x+1
   ...
end
```

I've seen [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238509/redundancy-in-ocaml-type-declaration-ml-mli), but its answer is unclear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `a.ml` is implicitly wrapped as the module `A` and the file `a.mli` is implicitly wrapped as the module type `A`.

So the following works

```
(* A.mli *)
val f : int -> int

(* A.ml *)
let f x = x + 1
```

And you would access `f` from another module as `A.f`.

Or if you really want submodules you could write

```
(* a.mli *)
module type A_SIG =
sig
    val f: int -> int
end

module A : A_SIG

(* a.ml *)
module type A_SIG =
sig
    val f: int -> int
end

module A : A_SIG =
struct
    let f x = x + 1
end
```

And you would access `f` from another module as `A.A.f` and the module `A` would also contain the signature `A_SIG`, in addition to the (sub)module `A`.

Implementations of Standard ML do not normally implicitly wrap the contents of a file as a module.

For completeness, note that OCaml has a feature to "generate" a module type from a module:

```
(* a.mli *)
module type A_SIG =
sig
    val f: int -> int
end

module A : A_SIG

(* a.ml *)
module A =
struct
    let f x = x + 1
end

module type A_SIG = module type of A
```